# How to find distinct elements from return result of Model.find() in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I'm creating a web app using node-js , mongoose and express. I have details of certain employees(Attendance details) for a particular month and I get details of all employees for that month depending on option selected from drop down on front end. After getting these documents I need to find employees that have a distinct employeeid.The variable 'docs' in callback consists of all the documents of employee details for a particular month and i need to find only distinct employeeid from those documents.Help appreciated.

```
app.get("/getSummary",(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.query.substr);
    Attendance.find({
        "date":{
            "$regex":req.query.substr,
            "$options": "i" 
        }
    }).then((docs)=>{


       if(docs.length == 0){
           console.log("empty");
           return res.status(404).send('No records for selected month found');
       }
       console.log("check: ",docs);
       var responseArr=[];

       res.status(200).send(docs);
    }).catch((err)=>{
        res.status(404).send(err);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Employees collection and attendance collection having employeeId.
Employees docs would look like :

```
[
  {_id:"1",name:"John Doe",...},
  {_id:"2",name:"Alex Foo",...},
  {_id:"3",name:"James Bar",...},
]
```

and attendance collection looks like :

```
[
  {date:'2019-06-22',employeeId:"1",start:"07:00:00 AM",end:"04:00:00 PM"},
  {date:'2019-06-22',employeeId:"2",start:"07:10:00 AM",end:"04:00:00 PM"},
  {date:'2019-06-22',employeeId:"3",start:"08:00:00 AM",end:"04:00:00 PM"},
  {date:'2019-06-23', employeeId:"1",start:"07:05:00 AM",end:"04:00:00 PM"},
  {date:'2019-06-23', employeeId:"2",start:"07:20:00 AM",end:"04:00:00 PM"},
  {date:'2019-06-23', employeeId:"3",start:"07:00:00 AM",end:"04:00:00 PM"},
]
```

If you need to get all records for every single user attendance during one month, then you will need aggregation to do that like :

```
Attendance.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
        "date": {
            $gte: new Date("2019-06-01"),
            $lt: new Date("2019-06-30")
        }
    }
  },
    {
    $group:{
        _id:"$employeeId",
        Attendance:{
            $addToSet:{
               date :"$date" ,
               start: "$start",
               end: "$end",                   
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    $lookup: {
       from: "employee",
       localField: "_id",
       foreignField: "_id",
       as: "Employee"
    }
 },     
])
```

this would return result like this:

```
[
  {
   _id:"1",
   Employee:{_id:"1",name:"John Doe",....}
   Attendance:[
       {date:'2019-06-22',start:"07:00:00 AM",end:"04:00:00 PM"},
       {date:'2019-06-23',,start:"07:05:00 AM",end:"04:00:00 PM"}, 
       ...   
  ],     
 },
 {
   _id:"2",
   Employee:{_id:"2",name:"Alex Foo",....}
   Attendance:[
       {date:'2019-06-22',start:"07:10:00 AM",end:"04:00:00 PM"},
       {date:'2019-06-23',start:"07:20:00 AM",end:"04:00:00 PM"}, 
       ...   
  ],     
 },
.... And so on
]
```

I assumed most of schema structure as you didn't define it in the question, hope this could help